# how to make nested-repeated fields in standard SQL(google-bigquery)

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to create a nested-repeated fields in
standard SQL,like this:https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated ?

for example,

input is:
[image: input is]

expected output is:
[image: expected output is]

Comment: For this exists the concepts of child tables and foreign-keys. You might want take a course or tutorial on database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array aggregation and struct in BigQuery as in the following example. `base` is the input and the following `select` query will produce the output you're after

```sql
WITH
base as (
select 'string1' as normalfield1, false as normalfield2, 200.0 as normalfield3, 'repeated field str1' as field1, 2.01 as field2, 201 as field3
UNION ALL
select 'string1', false, 200.0, 'repeated field str2', 4.01, 702)

select 
  normalfield1, 
  normalfield2, 
  normalfield3, 
  array_agg(struct(field1, field2, field3)) as repeatedData 
  from base 
  group by 1,2,3
```